# Understanding React browser history

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a web app using react 16 and react-router v4. My app has index.js like this -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";        
import App from "./components/App";
import Bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";        
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import "../assets/css/clean-blog.css";  
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter> , 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

My App.js looks like this -

```
"use strict";

import React              from "react";
import Header             from "./layout/header";
import Body               from "./layout/body";
import Footer             from "./layout/footer";

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
           <div>
             <Header />
             <Body /> 
             <Footer />
           </div>  
      );
  }

};

export default App;
```

In my Header component, I have a search box and I want that when user clicks on seacrh submit button, then they should be redirected to /seacrh url. I managed to get that. Please look at handleSubmit function

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Notifications, {notify} from 'react-notify-toast';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchTerm:''
        };    
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //console.log(this.props);
        //console.log(this.state.searchTerm);
        this.props.history.replace({
            pathname:'/search',
            searchTerm:this.state.searchTerm
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
                <div className="container">
                    <Link to='/'>My Library</Link>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link to='/authors'>Authors</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link to='/books'>Books</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} type="post">
                            <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.handleChange} name="searchTerm"/>
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md " type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>    

        );
    }



};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

This works fine when for all urls except when I try to submit from /search url then nothing happens. What I mean is that handleSubmit function gets called but then it does not fire the redirect call.

I am very new to react and would like to have some insight on how best should I handle this.